# What to modify in WSDL so that svcutil generates HttpsTransport for the binding in the config

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have deployed a Java metro web service that is being consumed by a WCF client. The service is accessed over https.

The WSDL gives the service location in the `soap:address` element as beginning with https. However the client accesses the WSDL itself at an independent http location (i.e. not through the service url).

The problem we have is that on the client side, the config that is generated by `svcutil.exe` from the WSDL has `httpTransport` instead of `httpsTransport` in the custom bindings. What, if anything, do I need to change in the WSDL so that svcutil will generate `httpsTransport` instead? How does svcutil decide which transport to generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the Metro web service with a ws-policy that requires transport security, through ws-security.

Once you do this, WCF will require HTTPS. This means you will also have to open IIS manager and enable the "Require SSL" option for the hosting site.

Comment: Thanks xOn. I am looking into this suggestion. Am I right in assuming that adding a security policy that requires ssl will make our service https only (i.e. it will not be accessible over plain http)?